# Unable to open a new Jupyter notebook [Permission denied]

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. When I run the

```
jupyter notebook
```

command from cmd, the notebook dashboard opens in the browser. But when I try to create a notebook using the new>python3 option, I get an error message which says 'Permission denied.'

Please help me out.

Comment: What is the prompt when you open CMD? `C:\>`? That folder is write protected

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jupyter-lab --notebook-dir=%USERPROFILE%` to always open in your home folder, which should have writable permissions

By default, Jupyter will use the directory where you started the command